# Can we split jquery.js in two parts?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to split jquery.js in two or three different part?

Currently I am using version 1.4.2, which is too heavy to load in 256kbps internet line.

Regards,

Vikas Parab

Comment: And how would spiting it into two files help? It'll still be the same size, except now in two HTTP requests.

Comment: But jQuery is only 24 KB big (when GZipped).

Comment: If the load of jQuery is too much for your customers you should overthink the use of jQuery and if you really need it. Which parts do you need? Would it be possible to write your wanted functionality without jQuery?

Comment: Yi Jiang is right here. If you split the file up you are technicaly slowing things down because the browser has to make more HTTP requests to the server, which is slower as they can only download one or two things at once (in most cases). Depending on what you need you could use a different JS library?

Answer (score 2):

Look at [jQuery's repository at GitHub](http://github.com/jquery/jquery), and at the Makefile there. You can adapt the build file (or Rakefile or Ant's build.xml) to only include the parts that you need.

Answer (score 2):

switch to a CDN hosted jQuery source to maximize the cache hit on the browser and link the min.js version in your pages (Just 24.1 kb)

http://softwareas.com/google-jquery-cdn

Answer (score 1):

Paul Irish states that you can effectively trim out all the parts that you don't think you'll ever need and suggests a way to do it here: http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to skip around the video, but you should watch the whole thing anyway--Paul is one of the jQuery masters!

This should help considerably if you're not using a lot of the library.

I hope this helps!

UPDATE: there's also a YouTube version which is more random-accessy.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_qE1iAmjFg  If you're impatient, skip to the 50m mark.

ALSO, I presume you ARE using the minified version?  If not, that is considerably smaller.

UPDATE 2: If you're only using the selector portions of jQuery, consider using Sizzle (http://sizzlejs.com/), which is part of jQuery anyway. (Sizzle is only like 4K minified)